# SQL Query to select one field order by other field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I want to select a field in select statement and order by with another field but sql server doesn't allows this as it says order by item must appear in the select statement if select distinct is specified.

This is what I tried :

```
select DISTINCT format_type
from Labels_Add_Label
where external_group_id= 2826
order by group_sequence
```

What changes are required to do in this query?

Please provide the changed query

Comment: When SELECT DISTINCT (or UNION, GROUP BY etc), only selected columns may be specified in the ORDER BY. (E.g. format_type = 1 can have group_sequence 1 and 3, and format_type = 2 can have group_sequence 2. I..e you don't know if format_type 1 (with 1 and 3) is before or after format_type 2 (with 2).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your query this way (equivalent to distinct):

```
SELECT format_type
FROM Labels_Add_Label
WHERE external_group_id= 2826
GROUP BY format_type;
```

and you can't use ORDER BY group_sequence here. There may be more than one row with same format_type but different group_sequence. SQL server doesn't know which one should be used for the ordering.

You can however use aggregate functions with a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT format_type
FROM Labels_Add_Label
WHERE external_group_id= 2826
GROUP BY format_type;
ORDER BY MIN(group_sequence) ;   -- or MAX(group_sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just took this question to test my knowledge and have come with the following solution (using CTE in MS SQL Server), please correct me if I'm wrong - Using the NORTHWIND Database (Employees Table) on MS SQL Server, I have written this query - This could be one other option that could be used, if there be a need to!

```
WITH CTE_Employees(FirstName, LastName, BirthDate)
AS
(
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, BirthDate 
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Region IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT FirstName FROM CTE_Employees ORDER BY BirthDate DESC
```

As mentioned above, there can be a same Employee FirstName but with a different LastName, hence SQL Server imposes a condition where we can't use DISTINCT in conjunction with ORDER BY...

Hope this helps!